# Unable to connect to Mysql 5.7 running as docker container from docker host using mysql client

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

After going through the following links from SOF- I still am facing the issue and there is no reasoning or solution available.

References:

- [Connecting to mysql docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752802/connecting-to-mysql-docker-container)
- [Connect to Docker MySQL container from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost)

Mysql 5.7 is running as container in my local machine. Once the server is up, connecting to the server using root or the new user created fails over localhost/0.0.0.0/127.0.0.1. Even after disabling the firewald, the connectivity failed with the same error.  I might have done something terribly wrong about this connectivity.  Any advice would be helpful.

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  service:
    image: mysql:5.7
    #build:
    #  context: ./
    #  dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: manage
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: manage
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testapp
    ports:
      - published: 3306
        target: 3306
```

Following is the output after **docker-compose up -d**

```sh
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
45ba02e6e457        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   52 seconds ago      Up 50 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

Below are the attempts to connect to the mysql container.

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -pmanage
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

mysql -u root -h 0.0.0.0 -pmanage
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -pmanage
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

IP of the running container works fine. But this is not a solution as the IP can change with time.

```
mysql -u root -h 172.31.0.2 -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.30 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

I am not looking for solutions with another docker command. How to connect to mysql container from docker host using mysql client.

Comment: Have you tried with the ip address of the running container? (`docker inspect <container>`)

Comment: Yes.  With IP address of the running the mysql container, connection works fine.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the problem is probably related due to the local mysql trying to connect over the socket file, instead of using a network socket. Can you try binding the socket to the local machine? (add volume `- /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`)

Comment: Ok. Tried and I got this error. "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)"

Comment: Just found this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001750/connect-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container-from-the-host

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to mysql in a docker container from the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001750/connect-to-mysql-in-a-docker-container-from-the-host)

Comment: `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp` the `33060` seems suspect to me here. Have you made a tweak in your MySQL to make it listen to `33060` rather than `3306` maybe?

Comment: Yes @ChristopheDeTroyer. Had set bind-address= 0.0.0.0 in /etc/my.cnf to make mysql listen over all interfaces .

Comment: No @β.εηοιτ.βε.  Made changes to mysqld. The change is bind-address= 0.0.0.0. No other change related to 33060

Comment: Mhm, ok, and so answering myself: MySQL image does expose `33060`, interesting. https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/Dockerfile#L89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--protocol=tcp` in your connection url.

```
mysql -u root -h localhost --protocol=tcp
```

Your mysql is running inside the docker container. So, you have to connect through TCP and local socket is not available for that. This is basically [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489879/1257729) of this question.

Comment: With a standard mysql:5.7, this works for root with --protocol. But when a custom cnf file is added (to alter max_packet_size), this approach does not work.